# XNA 2d rotation around centre

Tags: matrix, xna

I'm trying to include support for zooming and rotating my camera class, around the centre of the viewport.

In my application, I've already positioned sprites manually before entering the SpriteBatch.Begin code, according to where the camera is positioned (to make culling easier to implement).  Although each sprite is positioned manually, I would rather not rotate and scale each sprite individually.

I therefore am trying to use the matrixTransform argument on the SpriteBatch.Begin method.

Below is a hard-coded application I've made to illustrate the problem (using a Car.png content image).  The rotation isn't as fast as I'd expect (10 degrees rotation every frame?), and it rotates/zooms about the top left.  I would like it to rotate around the centre of the screen, which would always keep the middle car in the centre, and also scale from that point.

I have tried several combinations of creating matrix translations, reordering/adding/multiplying/translating by the halfway distance of viewport, but I don't really understand how matrices work.  I've also tried the solutions on several websites which I haven't managed to make work for me.

Can someone tell me the matrix translations I have to create, or point me in the direction of a website you think will work for my setup?

**Windows XNA application to demonstrate the problem:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace RenderTest
{
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        Texture2D _carTexture;
        float _zoom = 1.0f;
        float _rotationInDegrees = 0.0f;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            _carTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Car");
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            if (Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsKeyDown(Keys.Up)) // Zoom in key
                _zoom *= 1.1f;

            if (Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsKeyDown(Keys.Down)) // Zoom out key
                _zoom /= 1.1f;

            if (Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)) // Rotate anticlockwise key
                _rotationInDegrees -= 10;

            if (Keyboard.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)) // Rotate clockwise key
                _rotationInDegrees += 10;

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearClamp, DepthStencilState.None, RasterizerState.CullNone, null, GetMatrix(GraphicsDevice));

            spriteBatch.Draw(_carTexture, new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50), Color.White);//Square car placed top left
            spriteBatch.Draw(_carTexture, new Rectangle(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2 - 25, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2 - 50, 50, 100), Color.Green);//Car placed centre
            spriteBatch.Draw(_carTexture, new Rectangle(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2 + 100, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2 + 100, 50, 50), Color.Black);//Off centre but always within screen

            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }

        Matrix GetMatrix(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
        {
            Matrix translationMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(0, 0, 0);
            Matrix rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(MathHelper.ToRadians(_rotationInDegrees)));
            Matrix zoomMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(_zoom);

            Matrix compositeMatrix = translationMatrix * rotationMatrix * zoomMatrix;

            return compositeMatrix;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Lee

**Solution**

```
    Matrix GetMatrix(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
    {
        Matrix translateToOrigin = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-graphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2, -graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2, 0);
        Matrix rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(MathHelper.ToRadians(_rotationInDegrees));
        Matrix zoomMatrix = Matrix.CreateScale(_zoom);
        Matrix translateBackToPosition = Matrix.CreateTranslation(graphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2, graphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2, 0);

        Matrix compositeMatrix = translateToOrigin * rotationMatrix * zoomMatrix * translateBackToPosition;

        return compositeMatrix;
    }
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that culling is rarely a worthwhile optimisation for `SpriteBatch`, and even when it is, you don't usually have to be too accurate about it (you could disregard rotation and simply draw a larger area). ([See this answer](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9277/optimizing-an-xna-2d-game/9289#9289).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the same Rectangle each time, and do the positioning in the matrix.

The reason for this is that the matrix is applied to your sprites after they are positioned using rectangle. All subseqent matrix operations will treat (0,0) as the origin, instead of the center of the texture as you expected.

Comment: To my knowledge the rectangle is used to position the sprite.  I am drawing three individual sprites (which for simplicity, are of the same texture) in different places.  If I was to use the same rectangle would they not all be placed on top of each other?

Comment: Sorry, I posted that a bit hastily before realizing exactly what you want to do. You need to treat (0, 0) as the point where everything is rotated and scaled around, not (width / 2, height / 2).

Comment: Ok, I've now used four translations.  One moving everything up and to the left so that the centre of the car is at (0,0), rotate, zoom, and then translate back so that the centre of the car is at (width&height/2).  I think it's working, but the rotation still seems far too slow...

Comment: You seem to be converting to radians twice ;) *MathHelper.ToRadians(MathHelper.ToRadians(*

Comment: Nevermind, I was converting it to radians twice, copy/paste error!